# UX to collect multiple forms in mobile application

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, jquery, jquerymobile

In the current mobile web Application I am working with, there are multiple forms to be collected from users (10 forms) and each form looks similar to that in the image below

[image: registration]

What is the best UX for a scenario like this? I considered pagination, but I'm confused whether it is a good approach.

Comment: Would a single user be expected to complete all 10 forms or does a single user see one of the 10 forms?

Comment: What are these forms being used for? Additionally, are some of these form fields optional? Could they edit these fields?

Comment: Can these forms be combines in any way? Is the main function of the app filling the forms (is it a car rental where in the end you rent a car or is it a registration to some courses app so that the sole function of the app is to get those forms filled?)

Comment: This is similar to course registration app. So a student need to fill all the details in the form and for every course, 10 courses. So all the forms are mandatory .

Answer (score 1):

Well if I was designing this form, I would like to let the user know how many of such pages are there and how far his progress is. So like if there are 10 form, might be a small row of numbers with completed ones marked.

Additionally, I would have extracted the common factors like Phone Number, URL, Email and have a separate page for that so that they are not repeated. If possible, I would have made the Month, Date, Week, etc fields into a single or 2 fields with spinners to choose from. That way he has to use keyboard less and also looks like less work. Use progressive disclosure for each form where you show the next form after completing the first form. Something like this.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkUJtG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There's always a limit to the amount of information a user is willing to share, and that limit is exactly equal to the amount they want what's after this form.

If I was giving away a million dollars to whomever completed a form they would spend weeks filling out nonsensical pages of jibberish at the hope of reaching the end of the form and their prize of a million bucks.

The best UX experience is to have the **least amount of fields as possible** and then to break it up into manageable, *related* pages (especially for mobile).  And especially avoid typing, because typing on mobile is awful.

From your image you have Time/Date/Month/Week/Datetime... and to be honest, I have no idea why those exist and why they are ALL necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from your comment that this form is more like a course registration, reusing the user's information would be most efficient and only requiring new/unique information to be inputted per course vs. having the user enter in all the data for every course.

Reducing the amount of input required by the user and validating that information (selecting classes from a drop down list vs. entering class information) will help collect and maintain accurate data.

Finally, consolidating or eliminating unnecessary fields will make this form more likely to be filled in successfully by your mobile users.

For example: Date, Time, Month, Week can all be consolidated by a one drop down field like

Course 100 - 8.14.14 8am, 16week
Course 100 - 9.14.14 8am, 8week
Course 200 - 8.14.14 10am, 16week
Course 200 - 9.14.14 8am, 8week

Based on what the users are more likely to select courses by you can change the order of course, date, time, etc.